# Application of integration by parts for Sobolev function

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I want to prove the following Exercise: If $f \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n) \cap L^2(|x|^2dx)$, then

$$ ||f||_2^2 = - \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} x_j \partial_{x_j} (|f(x)|^2)dx. $$

My attempt so far: If $f \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, this follows from integration by parts. For general $f$, we have $g := |f|^2 \in W^{1,1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. By density, there exists a sequence $(g_k)_k \subset C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ s.t. $g_k \rightarrow g$ in $W^{1,1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. I would then like to take the limit $k \rightarrow \infty$ in
$$ ||g_k||_1 = - \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} x_j \partial_{x_j} g_k dx $$

to conclude. I am stuck showing that (hopefully)

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} x_j \partial_{x_j} g_kdx \rightarrow \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} x_j \partial_{x_j} g dx.$$

Any hints, also for possible different approaches, would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: The condition $f\in L^{2}(|x|^{2}dx)$ has not been used, how to use this condition?

Comment: Maybe we should consider $f_{k}\to f$ in $H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\cap L^{2}(|x|^{2}dx)$, and then we have$ \|f_{k}\|^{2}_{2}=-\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}x_{j}\partial_{x_{j}}(|f_{k}|^{2})dx$

Comment: Then $-\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}x_{j}\partial_{x_{j}}(|f_{k}|^{2})dx=-\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}2x_{j}f_{k}f_{kx_{j}}dx$

Comment: At last, by Cauchy inequality we have $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}2x_{j}f_{k}f_{kx_{j}}dx\leq 2(\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}|f_{k}|^{2}|x|^{2}dx)^{1/2}(\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}|f_{kx_{j}}|^{2}dx)^{1/2}$

Comment: So, to prove $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}x_{j}\partial_{x_{j}}(|f_{k}|^{2}-|f|^{2})dx\to 0$, we have$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}x_{j}(2f_{k}f_{kx_{j}}-2ff_{x_{j}})dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}x_{j}(2f_{k}f_{kx_{j}}-2f_{k}f_{x_{j}}+2f_{k}f_{x_{j}}-2ff_{x_{j}})dx$, then using Cauchy inequality we can get the result. I don't know if it is right, it is just my own idea.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am struggeling exactly with the first part of your comment, namely the approximation in $H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\cap L^{2}(|x|^{2}dx)$. I am unsure what norm this space is equipped with and how to argue that $C_c^\infty$ is dense in it. 

If one is able to construct a sequence $(f_k)_k \subseteq C_c^\infty$ s.t. $||f_k - f||_{H^1} \rightarrow 0$ and $||xf_k - xf||_{L^2} \rightarrow 0$, then I agree that your proposed solution works.

Comment: So, I also want to know whether there is a sequence $f_{k}\to f$ in $H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\cap L^{2}(|x|^{2}dx)$